# Angular | NgFor to display the array contents

Tags: angular, express

I am new to Angular and trying to get the values inside **postdata**, but when i am trying to iterate over it , its only giving me the first value.
Attaching my code:

```
 posts;

 constructor(private getpostservice:GetpostsService) { }

 ngOnInit(): void {
  this.getpostservice.getposts().then(data=>{
  this.posts = [data];

  console.log("Inside home",this.posts);
 })
}
```

This is my html logic:

```
<tr *ngFor="let p of posts;index as i">


        <td>
          {{p.postdata[i].title}}
        </td>

      </tr>
```

[image: This is data format].

Can someone help me to extract title and body please?

Comment: try changing to let p of posts.postdata and then <td>
          {{p.title}}
        </td>

Comment: Why are you storing your data as array `this.posts = [data];`? If your request response data is an array, you would have an array of arrays - bad idea. And if its just an object, then you would not need a loop to iterate over it.

Comment: @Fussel sir, can you please give an alternative way to render the data in angular?
It would be very much helpful.

Comment: May be you are looking for nested *NgFor in this case something like here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tj8kxt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are trying to achieve based on your console data is:

```
 constructor(private getpostservice:GetpostsService) { }

 ngOnInit(): void {
  this.getpostservice.getposts().then(data => {
    this.posts = data.postdata;
    console.log("Inside home",this.posts);
 });
```

and

```
<ng-container *ngIf="posts">
  <tr *ngFor="let p of posts">
    <td>
      {{p.title}}
    </td>
  </tr>
</ng-container>
```

Maybe you should also consider using `Observables` instead of `Promises`, it's a bit you have to get used to but it is way more powerful and more easy to use.

Comment: Yeah some opinion about using Observable instead of Promise, or another alternative is using the async pipe